# Printing out partially unique data after querying a db

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble finguring out how to use the table data like I need to... my table consists of a category name column (which has the same value for many subcategories) and the other column contains subcategory names.

For example:

```
col1        col2
------------------
apples      fruits
oranges     fruits
pears       fruits
honda       cars
volvo       cars
audi        cars
```

I am trying to write a select statement that selects all the data from the database and prints out the category name once ONLY, while printing out all subcategories that, that particular category name includes.

Something like:

**Fruits:**

- Apples
- Oranges
- Pears

**Cars:**

- Honda
- Volvo
- Audi

Comment: @Truth you might want to avoid changing the question's meaning when reformatting it. It now implies that MHZ wants everything in one column (which may or may not be the case).

Comment: @Vatev: If you'd looked at the original code of the question ([let me help you!](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58cf3e90-4f5e-4788-ab5b-0eb33f81bb7f/view-source)) You'd know why I edited it the way I did :)

Comment: @Truth Sorry, I was only looking at the formatted versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    col2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(col1 SEPARATOR ',') as stuff
FROM table1
GROUP BY col2
```

If you want the '-' in front of the names you can use `CONCAT('-',col1)` instead of `col1`.

This php code will transform the result into a 1 dimensional array

```
$conn = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db_name');

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if (!($rs = $conn->query("
        SELECT
            col2,
            GROUP_CONCAT(col1 SEPARATOR ',') as stuff
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY col2
    "))) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);
    exit();
}


$result = array();
while ($row = $rs->fetch_object()){
    $result[] = $row->col2;
    if(!empty($row->stuff)) $result = array_merge($result,explode(',',$row->stuff));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Without an explanation how the category is separated from the subcategory names, this does not help me much. Also, why is group_concat neccessary in the select statement? it just adds a comma?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is an [aggregate function](http://infogoal.com/sql/sql-aggregate.htm) (like SUM,COUNT,AVG...) but instead performing math on the values it concatenates them together with the specified `SEPARATOR`.

Comment: You should really try to check if the result is correct by running the query directly in a MySQL client. Also this answer will give you 2 columns - 1-st will be the category (col2) 2-nd will be the things (col1) which are in the category separated by ','. I am no longer sure that is the answer you need.

Comment: your method **does not** work. When I go and try to print out the rows after using mysql fetch array and while loop, it returns a string of subcategories without returning the category...

Comment: I may be wrong about this but i don't think re-posting the same comment again counts as having a conversation.

Comment: the edited version of the original post is exactly what I need. I need to be able to print out the col2 once as a heading and all the subcategories pertaining to that category underneath it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: In that case this solution is not what you need, and I can't think of any simple way of doing it in MySQL. I will add an example php script which transforms the result into a flat array.

Answer (score 0):

What you  is it recommended. Moreover, it would make your life with an array very difficult. Consider trying something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $cat = $row['col2'];
   $item = $row['col1'];
   $array[$cat] = $item;
}
```

Now you have an array with categories as keys and items as values for each of those keys.

Good luck!

Comment: can you please explain why is it not recommended? also, i am not using arrays... thanks for the response though

Comment: Well, I slightly misread your question. The answer by Vatev does exactly what you want. If you used what I did, you could do this: `$cars = implode(', ', $array['cars']);` and have the same comma-separated string for the cars. That way, MySQL is doing less work, giving you more flexibility.