# Creating a bullet list using mysql table data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
subcategory    category
------------------------
apples         fruits
oranges        fruits
pears          fruits
honda          cars
volvo          cars
audi           cars
```

What would be an easy way to print out something like the example below, using php and mySQL?

Example:

**Fruits:**

- Apples
- Oranges
- Pears

**Cars:**

- Honda
- Volvo
- Audi

I have been trying to figure this out for hours now, I appreciate any advice.

Comment: At least tell us where you're getting stuck. Querying MySQL? generating valid HTML markup? Etc...

Comment: [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710271/printing-out-partially-unique-data-after-querying-a-db/11710306#11710306) might help those who are wondering what exactly is being asked here.

Comment: coming up with the php to iterate through the query and create a list like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of categories, and then subcategories in each categories.

```
<?php

$categories = array();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $category = $result['category'];
    $categories[$category][] = $result['subcategory'];
}
```

This will then give you a multidimensional array, with categories and the keys, and the sub-categories as the values. You can loop over them as thus:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category => $subcategories): ?>
  <li>
    <?php echo $category; ?>
    <ul>
<?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
      <li><?php echo $subcategory; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am getting the following error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach" the $results variable contains mysql data returned from the select query...

Comment: Have you actually altered to code to match yours? Given you haven't posted any of your code I've had to assume, where `$results` is your database result set. If your variable's named differently, then change it. You just appear to be expecting people to write the exact answer for you to just copy and paste—you're not going to learn much doing that.

Comment: I am not expecting for anyone to write my code, I was just trying to understand why the foreach statement returned an error, because the $results are the results returned from the mysql database from the select statement that I wrote, so it shouldn't have returned an error, thats all...

Comment: Well I couldn't possibly begin to diagnose given you've not posted any code yourself. If you have your database results in a `$results` variable, then it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = getData();
$dataByCat = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
   $dataByCat[$row['category']][] = $row;
}
```

`$dataByCat` will be an array in the "shape" of your bullet points.

Comment: this generates an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getData() in D:\Hosting\9453412\html\cats.php on line 52

Comment: Treate this as pseudocode...getData is a made up function which returns the data from mysql

Comment: You didn't really say what you're question was...I took a gander that you were asking how to make a nested array out of a flat array...

Comment: how does your code accomplish creating a category, sub-category style list, from a select statement that gets all the data displayed in the table in the original post?

Comment: The foreach statement will create a nested array